# Apache won't start in XAMPP v3.0.12

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I want to setup a localhost server using XAMPP v3.0.12.
But apache won't start.
Earlier I got the error message "port 80 or 443 ssl already in use installing apache2.2 service failed"...
I found out that skype was using port 80. I fixed it and reinstalled XAMPP..This time I didn't get any error message...
but still  Apache won't start,,
I tried to start Apache from the xampp control panel but it just won't start..

Comment: Have you checked whether your php.ini file is in place? also have you tried to manually set up a virtual host by editing `httpd-vhosts.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting apache by running `xampp/apache_start.bat` file and it will print you what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Reinstall Xampp.

---

2) Start Xampp.

---

3) Click on 'Config' button for Apache.

---

4) Click on 'Apache(httpd.confg).

---

5) Find '80' and replace it with '8080' and save.

---

6) Again click on 'Config' button for Apache.

---

7) Click on 'Apache(httpd-ssl.confg).

---

8) Find '443' and replace it with '4433' and save.

---

9) Now Start Apache.
`